# New % Column to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

It might sound simple to do but I'm trying to add a percentage column to a massive dataframe but I have no idea how to deal with this:

Let's say that my df structure is the following:

```
date          month      amount       new column %
2015-01-01        1       50    50/sum(amount/month)
2015-01-02        1       100   100/sum(amount/month)
2015-01-03        1       200   200/sum(amount/month)
```

My problem is: how do I sum the month on the divisor, when I have data for several years and months.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` you can do:

```
data <- data %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarise(`new colum %` = amount / sum(amount))
```

which will give you the fraction for each month.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've tried this got NA's returned. I need a % per day not per month. Month sum will only be used for the % formula (in the divisor).

Comment: That suggests that there are NA values in your `amount` column, Try `sum(amount, na.rm = TRUE)` which will return the sum ignoring the NA values. 
If you need the fraction per day, use your date column as a grouping variable. Make sure your dates are of a proper class (e.g. `Date`).